# Is there a way to check multiple private (i.e. login required) forums without visiting each one separately?

Tags: windows, forum

I read several message boards each day and I would like a way to see all of them at once, sort through the read/unread items, and search posts. Basically I'm thinking of something like Google Reader with RSS feeds. However, at least one of the forums I read does not have an RSS feed.

A quick Google search brought up [ForumPilot](http://forumpilot.com/index.html).

However, it can't seem to identify my forum engine so it fails. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Web Forum Reader](http://www.chemtable.com/WebForumReader.htm) can do this. I'm not sure about the searching feature, but it will conveniently display new topics so you can sort through them easily.

[image]

> Web Forum Reader is uniquely designed
>   for reading Internet forums and
>   conferences. You can easily add your
>   favorite forums to Web Forum Reader to
>   stay informed about updates and
>   changes on these forums without
>   loading them in your browser. Web
>   Forum Reader saves you time by showing
>   new and updated topics while hiding
>   topics you have already read. Web
>   Forum Reader will also reduce the
>   amount of data you download compared
>   to regular reading using a browser.
>   Use Web Forum Reader's handy Resource
>   Addition Wizard to add Internet forums
>   and conferences.

A Lite (free) version is available as well as a paid version.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the forums offer an RSS feed of the forums.  RSS Feeds can be passworded, and protected, so it maybe as simple as using an RSS feeder, with your account information.

Comment: One of the forums he frequents does not have a feed

Comment: Yes, but even if 50% of the forums he watches has RSS feeds, it will make it easier to monitor the others....